Is there a way to crop the display of a SVG using CSS?
I am creating a component similar to MudRating to display the average of the ratings an item is given. So unlike MudRating which only allows integer values of 1 - 5, this will generally get a rating that's a double. For example 3.21 or 4.88.
At present MudBlazor only has empty, half, and full star. So the ratings have to be displayed as:

And these are rendered (RatingAverage.razor) as:
@for (var i = 0; i < numFullStars; i++)
{
    <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Star" Color="Color.Warning" />
}

@if (showHalfStar)
{
    <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarHalf" Color="Color.Warning" />
}

@for (var i = startEmptyStars; i < 5; i++)
{
    <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarOutline" Color="Color.Warning" />
}

Here's my question. Is there a way to render the partial star as:
<MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarOutline" Color="Color.Warning" />
<MudIcon Crop="0,0, @width ,1" Position="OnTopStarOutline" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Star" Color="Color.Warning" />

where:

The Position="OnTopStarOutline" (clearly needs to be something else) will render the Star on top of the StarOutline
the @width is a value from 0.0 to 1.0 that crops the Star to that percentage of the width, so it only overwrites the leftmost of StarOutline it is over.

Is there a way to accomplish this? And if so, how? And I assume this is a CSS question. But if there's another way, please enlighten me.

I also asked about another approach but I prefer this approach - if it can be done.

you should not duplicate discussions. Use one discussion only

@FabrizioCalderan I have had numerous questions closed recently for having too broad a question (in the Blazor topics). So I am now writing very very focused questions to not get hit for that. Personally I agree with you - but I'm following the rules as they're being enforced.

This is fundamentally bad UX, though. Half a star horizontally by width fills half the area, due to its symmetry, but that's not true for your other examples - the width and area wouldn't match and both would be hard to determine. You could get closer using the five-fold rotational symmetry (0.21 -> 0.2 and 0.88 -> 0.9) but even this would be very hard to discriminate unless the stars were very large. If you need more precision, show a number rather than stars.

@jonrsharpe I think the percentage fill works for stars because the human eye is not looking for the percentage of the shape filled, but just how much of the left is filled. And people are not going to say that's only 21%, not 27%. With that said, I'd be fine with a 1/4 and 3/4 filled star and use the closest. What is off is a rating of 3.26 and 3.74 use a half filled star - that's too far off. And you are correct that there should be a number - but it should be there also, not instead. I see that a lot.

https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/wvdKRPx

Use clip path. I can't use MudIcon in snippet so these round <span>s are only for demonstration. In your code just set --width and apply the clip-path on your icons:


.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.icon::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: inset(0 calc(100% - var(--width, 0%)) 0 0);
}
<span class="icon" style="--width:10%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:20%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:30%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:40%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:50%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:60%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:70%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:80%"></span>
<span class="icon" style="--width:90%"></span>



Edit: More explanation
The clip-path CSS property is a way to visually limit an element to a specific region, sort of like a stencil. It's very similar to the <clipPath> element in SVG, but since it's an CSS property, it can access CSS variables (aka custom properties). So I also combine it with --width (a custom property, you can name it whatever you want) to dynamically construct a clip rectangle based on the desired width.
inset() means distant from 4 edges of its original box. It has similar syntax to other box-related property, so the calc(100% - var(--width, 0%)) means distant from right edge equals 100% minus --width (if --width is missing, default to 0%).
Check the linked MDN page, they have more details and examples.

This looks (about to implement it) to be exactly it - thank you. Can you please explain what is happening here? TIA

I edited to add some more explanation. Feel free to ask if you need something else.
